# Word embeddings through SVD - Why are the singular values thrown away?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, word2vec, word-embeddings

Word embeddings are created from matrix factorization of the word- word co-occurrences matrix X through SVD.
So if we factorize X = USV and if we are taking only k significant singular values into consideration then the word embeddings that we take is 
U' = [u1 u2 ... uk]. If we take the matrix of first k singular values to be S'
shouldn't the word embeddings matrix be given by U'*(S'^0.5). When we are taking only U' as the word embedding matrix we are ignoring the weight along each independent direction and treating them equal . Any thoughts ?